# Aligning the view to center

Tags: java, android

I want to place the two text horizontally at the center. It is very easy to put it directly in a layout. 
But what i am trying to achieve is :

Testapplayout.xml: This is set as content view of the activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.example.testapp.Customlayout
    android:id="@+id/custom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
 </com.example.testapp.Customlayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

class Customlayout

public class Customlayout extends LinearLayout {

```
public Customlayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public Customlayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public Customlayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}
```

}

Now on the Testapplayout, customlayout, I am trying to inflate the layout to show the texts at the center:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center|bottom"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status_text"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
```

This still comes at the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.example.testapp.Customlayout
   android:id="@+id/custom"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true">

 </com.example.testapp.Customlayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Can you please help me explain, why that so.

Comment: Relative layout give you the facility to align thing accordingly and in that the trick was android:layout_centerInParent="true" what -ever this view is this line will force the view to be in the center of the whole layout